# Word tables. text skewed between cells in the row

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, alignment, cell-format

The image below demonstrates the issue. (using Word from 'Microsoft office 365 Apps' product is up to date at the time of post)

[image]

The gap is due to special characters and an equation input. It's most visible at the bottom, where the table isn't even on both sides (as circled).

Unfortunately, it is minor for now... however, progressively, it becomes worse as the gap increases. Super annoying, the text on the left needs to align with the right within the table (as shown by the red line). I've attempted to use the ruler and table properties but haven't had any luck trying to fix it. However, I ran into a solution regarding the addition of cells and blank borders, which unfortunately doesn't meet the documents' future needs.

I couldn't find anything anywhere regarding a direct resolution to the issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

(Edit: the table is correctly formatted and aligned, the borders go to the end of the page on each side)

Comment: Cells formatting is independent. You may use, for example, fixed distance between lines in the paragraph (in pixels), and the rows won't move apart.

Comment: @Akina, how would I apply that?

Comment: If you add rows, those will start the spacing over. You should not be using the Enter key for spacing. Start a new row instead. See http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/concepts/rules_enterparagraphs.html and http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/4UseTablesTabs.htm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want paragraphs in neighbouring cells (columns) to be vertically aligned, you need to make sure to have text with:

- same font and font size
- same line spacing
- 0 spacing before and after paragraphs

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. All my spacing matched and was aligned. The issue is caused by special characters, images, and tables. Ideally, the text row is equal to each other so that if the above are used, the formating retains an equal line measurement in each cell (As seen in my original post, I had used an equation insert). To be completely clear, I have no clue if this is possible.